# Animating divs on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'm hardly trying to find a good solution for creating smooth animations on mobile devices, especially on android.

First I found out that using javascript is no option -> android is SOO sadly slow with it

Then I found CSS-transitions -> android still horrible lagging

Then I found [this](http://swipejs.com/) script and seems to work fine (webkit transformation?)

Can you tell me how to do it right? Maybe there are better ways..
Also I don't really want to use a third-party script, even if it is lightweight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android supports css transitions since at least version 2.1 http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

what are u exactly aiming at? what browsers, and on what devices are you testing? keep in mind that slowness could be happening because hardware and not software limitations

Comment: I was trying to move an empty div container with 100% width and height on my Galaxy S3. Even my old ipod is doing smoother movements.

Comment: then it's all fault of the crappy android browser! :) have you tried it on e.g. chrome for android?